# Where goes my messages from service?

Tags: c#, web-services, event-log

In C# VS2008 I have a service which can run from command line and as registered service.
I am trying to debug my Service process I wondered why it does not write logs in event viewer.
I have a logger as this:

```
public static void Log(string s, EventLogEntryType et) {
        try {
            if (CService.asService) {
                if (!EventLog.SourceExists("Jobs")) {
                    EventLog.CreateEventSource("Jobs", "JobsServiceLog");
                }
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Jobs", s,
                    et, 234);
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Then somewhere I am logging:
    Log("Jobs service started", EventLogEntryType.Information);

Nothing is appear in the Event Viewer->JobsServiceLog.

What can be reason?

thanks

Arman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's up with CService.asService? are you sure the source gets created?

Comment: CService.asService=true; and service is started I can connect it by client.

Comment: i believe your problem is with the creation  of the EventSource

Comment: Do you mean EventLog.CreateEventSource?

Comment: yes, I believe the event source is not being created, thus, you don't see the entry on the Event Viewer